# WPF Button DataTrigger not setting Content correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm making a class, inherting from `Window` which adds some additional functionality to the TitleBar.

I have tried to recreate the Windows 10 title bar using this XAML as the minimize, restore/maximize and close buttons:

```xml
            <Button x:Name="CloseButton"
                    Click="CloseButton_Click"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Content="&#xE106;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="10" Padding="15,10" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Foreground="White"
                    DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"/>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>

            <Button x:Name="MaximizeButton"
                    Click="MaximizeButton_Click"
                    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="10" Padding="15,10" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Foreground="White">
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Setter Property="Button.Content" Value="&#xE739;" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=WindowState}" Value="Maximized">
                                <Setter Property="Button.Content" Value="&#xE923;" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}, Path=WindowState}" Value="Normal">
                                <Setter Property="Button.Content" Value="&#xE739;" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>

            <Button x:Name="MinimizeButton"
                    Content="&#xE949;"
                    Click="MinimizeButton_Click"
                    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="10" Padding="15,15,15,5" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Foreground="White">
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"/>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
```

The problem is that while my Maximize button correctly displays like this, initially:

[image: button default appearance]

If I click it, it turns into this:

[image: button after clicking]

Which looks like a sort of invalid character? It is a valid character according to [Segoe UI MDL2 icon guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font).

If I then click it again to restore it, the restore works correctly but the icon stays the same and doesn't change back to the correct image, this:

[image: after restore click]

Is there something wrong with my `Style` or `DataTrigger`?

You'll note I've tried `AncestorType={x:Type Window}}` and `AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}`, `MainWindow` being my class, but neither of these made any difference.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the second trigger? You only want to show a different icon and trigger and when the window is `Maximized`, don't you?

Comment: I added that second trigger in an attempt to get it to restore correctly, but it didn't work - so I've tried it without that and it had the same behaviour (i.e. incorrect image displayed and not corrected when no longer maximized).

Comment: I am afraid your issue is not reproducible.

Comment: Ah, I realised I was doing some stupid stuff in the `MaximizeButton_Click` button which was causing the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I realised I was setting the `Button.Content` in the `MaximizeButton_Click` method, which I'd forgotten about. Removing that and it all works as expected.